# Uploading Multiple Files To S3 Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, promise, sails.js

I am trying to upload multiple files to `S3` from my `Sails.js`application. I've a Controller to handle the Request and a `Service` to upload should in case multiple controllers wants to utilize the function. The promise in the controller doesn't get resolved. And also, I keep getting this error **Unhandled rejection TimeoutError: Missing credentials in config**

**Controller**

```
multiSizeCreate: (req, res) => {

    UploadService.uploadFile(req).then((data, failure) => {
        if (failure) return [null];
        return [Promise.resolve(AWSService.s3awsupload(data))];<-- <--The promise doesn't get resolved
    })
    .spread(uploadedData => {
        if (!uploadedData) return ResponseService.json(403, res, 'File upload failed');
        console.log(uploadedData); <--It logs an unresolved promise
        return ResponseService.json(201, res, 'Size(s) created successfully');
    })
    .catch(err => ValidationService.jsonResolveError(err, Size, res))
}
```

**AWSService**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const fs = require('fs');
const key = sails.config.settings.aws.key;
const secret = sails.config.settings.aws.secret;
const bucket = sails.config.settings.aws.bucket;
_ = require('lodash');
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: key, secretAccessKey: secret});
const Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = {

    s3awsupload: (files) => {

        let toUpload = []
        if (files.length > 0) {
            _.forEach(files, file => {
                toUpload.push(awsmainUpload(file));
            });
            return [toUpload];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

const awsmainUpload = (fileDirectory) => {

    const uploadImage = fs.createReadStream(fileDirectory.fd);
    const fileName = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const params = {Bucket: bucket, Key: fileName + " " + fileDirectory.fileName, Body: uploadImage};

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.upload(params, (error, outpout) => {
            return error ? reject(error) : resolve(outpout);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Try not omitting the `Promise.resolve()` wrapper. Also there's no point wrapping your null/result in an array just to upwrap it with `.spread()`. You should end up with `return failure ? null : AWSService.s3awsupload(data)`, and `.then()` instead of `.spread()`.

Comment: Sorry, that should read "Try *omitting* the Promise.resolve() wrapper.... "

Comment: I have fixed the issue few minutes after posting the question. This was helpful though: `return failure ? null : AWSService.s3awsupload(data), and .then()` because, I thought `.spread()` is a must use. Now, I know it's meant to resolve array of promises